# Spring Batch Json custom ItemWriter

Tags: java, json, spring-batch

I want to write json format files from a database.
I have this prototype of `ItemWriter` implementation, very simple.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class CustomItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>, StepExecutionListener {
    private Gson gson;
    private Resource resource;
    private boolean shouldDeleteIfExists = true;
    private List<T> allItems = new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("this is the begin " + items.size());
        allItems.addAll(items);
    }

    public Resource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public boolean isShouldDeleteIfExists() {
        return shouldDeleteIfExists;
    }

    public void setShouldDeleteIfExists(boolean shouldDeleteIfExists) {
        this.shouldDeleteIfExists = shouldDeleteIfExists;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution arg0) {
        //write ALL to the output file
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(allItems)); 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution arg0) {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").disableHtmlEscaping().create();
    }
}
```

The problem solved here, is that the `write` method sends to the output file each `commitInterval` a JSON array, I just wanted a unique JSON array in my file.

Implementing `StepExecutionListener` after the step runs; I can send to the output file the entire array and transform it to JSON, and write it to the output file (fine!).

My question is, **Is this the correct way to do that?** I think in the benefit of write to the file each `commitInterval`, but I'm not sure with my solution. It works, but I don't want to solve this problem and to provake another.

Answer (score 2):

You want to actually flush the write to your file with each chunk otherwise you'll lose restartability.

Assuming you're okay with one JSON object per line, I would probably just use a `FlatFileItemWriter` in combination with a custom `LineAggregator` that converts each object to a JSON string. Something along these lines:

```
public class JsonLineAggregator<T> implements LineAggregator<T>, StepExecutionListener {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private boolean isFirstObject = true;

    @Override
    public String aggregate(final T item) {
        if (isFirstObject) {
            isFirstObject = false;
            return "[" + gson.toJson(item);
        }
        return "," + gson.toJson(item);
    }

    public void setGson(final Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if (stepExecution.getExecutionContext().containsKey("isFirstObject")) {
            isFirstObject = Boolean.parseBoolean(stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getString("isFirstObject"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext().putString("isFirstObject", Boolean.toString(isFirstObject));
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated the `LineAggregator` implementation above to demonstrate how you'd make it output something that looked like an JSON list.

Note that you'd also want to register a `FlatFileFooterCallback` to your `FlatFileItemWriter` that added the final "]".

```
public class JsonFlatFileFooterCallback implements FlatFileFooterCallback {

    @Override
    public void writeFooter(final Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are many JSON objects per line, I need to write always an array to the file, this will do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... Each "item" of generic type `T` passed to the writer in the `write(List<T> items)` method will get its own line in your file using this setup

Comment: Added detail in the answer above to show you how you could make your final output look like a JSON list (which I think is what you were asking)

Comment: Ok, the generated file has n-objects lines, my implementation writes all objects in a single line, but I like your solution because the `commitInterval` doesn't lose it reason.

Comment: If you want it to be all on one line, you can set the `lineSeparator` on the `FlatFileItemWriter` to be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for a Solution .

In Xml you can add this like that .

```
    <property name="resource" value="file:opt/output.json" />  <!--  #{jobParameters['input.file.name']} -->
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean
            class="com.package.JsonLineAggregator">
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```